# Generate search results for users by city in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, devise

At the moment I am trying to create a search within a project to bring up users depending on their region. From what I understand, I basically need to place the search params in the controller, the self.search method in the model, and then the form in the view.

In another project, I have a search but it shows all the options above and use the search to filter out those which do not match. For this situation, I do not want to list any users in the beginning. I want to use the search bar and bring up any users that match within that view page. Additionally I use Devise for users if that does make a difference. Here are my three regions of code:

Model (user.rb):

```
def self.search(search)
where("state ILIKE ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

Controller (welcome_controller.rb):

```
def index
    @users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    @newusers = User.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
    @differentlocations = User.all.group_by(&:state).count
render :layout => 'with_newest_members'
if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

View (find.html.erb):

```
<%= form_tag(find_path, :method => "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Please let me know if you have any knowledge for me to help =) Any additional explanation would be greatly appreciated to help me understand, thank you!

Edit: I know I need to enter the results portion but I am confused about how/where to put it.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER:

The issue was in my controller because I had a render command prior to the search code. The controller should be:

```
def index
@users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
@newusers = User.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(5)
@differentlocations = User.all.group_by(&:state).count
if params[:search]
@users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
 else
@users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
render :layout => 'with_newest_members'
end
```

Fantastic =)

Answer (score 0):

Two small things that might help:

1)  In your Search model, I believe you have a typo in your `search` method. It should read as follows:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("state LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

You might also want to consider a more description name for your argument, such as `state`.

2)  In your form, you don't need to explicitly write `params[:search]` anywhere. The params hash will be generated for you in the controller, with the name of the text_field as the key and the value inputted by the user as the value (see Ruby docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements)). In this case, use `:search` as the name of the text_field_tag name.

```
<%= form_tag(find_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

More on FormHelpers [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

Comment: I appreciate the input but it did not work =( 1. I don't have a search model, this is going under my user model, since I am searching users. The reason I had ILIKE instead of LIKE is because I read if using Postgress (which I am), I may need to use ILIKE instead, but unsure if that is absolutely true. 2: Thank you for the resources and good to know but when I don't put the params, then the search field has the word "search" inside of it. Regardless of these, I still do not have a result displayed.

Comment: You're right - `ILIKE` isn't a typo; it provides [case insensitive matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE). On #2, I should have been more clear. The text_field_tag uses the following syntax: `text_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`.  In your code, you had `:search` as the field name and `params[:search]` as the value. Don't use `params[:search]` as the value. Leave the value blank. Rails will use the name of the field (:search) and the user's inputted value to pass `params[:search] => "whatever the user inputs"` to your controller.